# ASP.NET MVC 3: Cascading ComboBox with EF

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik-mvc

Hi fellow StackOverflow Members,

I'm tired of bumping my head on the wall, so I would like to explain my problem here, hoping to get a solution for it.

I'm developing an ASP.NET applications, using C# and Razor. I've also implemented the Telerik.MVC.UI for Grid displays.

What I'm trying to do now is, on my Create form, show some sort of Cascading Comboboxes.
I found a lot of tutorials on the internet, explaining how, however, my database structure isn't 
identical.
Most tutorials work with 2 or 3 tables (Entities), but all my data fields are in one table.

My table is constructed as follows:
ID    Division    Department    Country

So I would like to have the first dropdown to show a SELECT DISTINCT of Country, next I would like to see the matching Departments, and last I'm searching for the matching Divisions.
As mentionned above, this is all within a create form, so upon POST, I want to pass the related ID to the Controller Action.

Any help is appreciated, as I'm totally stuck...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Telerik 2012 Q1 is released! it supports casscading combobox internally. check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use strongly typed view models. Make a viewmodel for your division, department, and country (basically a class which holds a list<> of each field from your db table). In your controller fill the viewmodel holding all three from the database and then pass it in `return view(viewmodel)`. In your view you can then use someHtmlHelperFor(model.division or model.department,etc.).